# Getting pointer to a vector of objects for vkGetSwapChainImagesKHR

Tags: c++, vector, c++17, shared-ptr, vulkan

I'm working on a class object for my Vulkan application and I'm now modifying the code for the `SwapChain` object. I'm in the transition of adding functionality for the `DepthBuffer`.

Originally within `SwapChain::create(/*...*/)` there is a call to `vkGetSwapChainImagesKHR()`. It was being called like this:

```
vkGetSwapChainImagesKHR(*device_, swapChain_, &imageCount_, nullptr);
images_.resize(imageCount);
vkGetSwapChainImagesKHR(*device_, swapChain_, &imageCount, images_.data());
```

Where `images_` is declared as `std::vector<VkImage> images_` in the `SwapChain`'s header.

---

Instead of having my objects write their own `createImage` and `createImageView` functions... I've decided to make `Image` as a stand-alone class object. I've done this already with many several Vulkan objects following a similar interface pattern for all of my classes. When one Vulkan class object contains another instead of storing `raw`  Vulkan types, they now store either an `std::shared_ptr<class T>` or an `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<class T>>` type.

---

Now back to my `SwapChain` class. It's member `images_` is no longer: `std::vector<VkImage>` it is now a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Image>>` where `Image` is a class that is wrapped around `VkImage` with all of the necessary functions for creating and cleaning up the Vulkan resources.

---

As for my question: How would I now call `vkGetSwapChainImagesKHR()`?

```
// this is straight forward...
std::vector<VkImage> images_;
vkGetSwapChainImagesKHR(*device_, swapChain_, &imageCount, images_.data()); 

// this is where I'm stuck...
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Image>> images_;
vkGetSwapChainImagesKHR(*device_, swapChain_, &imageCount_, ??? ); // &images_.data(), images_.get()...
```

How do I get the appropriate type that `vkGetSwapChainImagesKHR()` requires for its last parameter?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can assume that the data *pointed to* by a vector of `shared_ptr` will be in contiguous memory. Only that the memory for those `shared_ptr` objects will be. But I'm certainly not 100% about this.

Comment: @AdrianMole ...and therefore I'm stuck... I could just leave the swap chain as is... and for other classes that contain just a single VkImage, use my class there, ... but I like the idea of things being contained in smart pointers... it makes for easy cleanup and less memory leaks.

Comment: It may depend on how you allocate and/or load your `shared_ptr` vector. If you do it by 'conversion' from a raw pointer array (from `new[]` or some such), then maybe just the address given by the first element's `get()`??

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm not using `new` or new[]` explicitly. All of my classes have default empty constructors. They all have an initialize function that must be called first. They take either a `VkDevice*`, `VkPhysicalDevice*`, both, and or some other possible pointers. It checks to see if they are `nullptr` and if so throws a message, if not it assigns the pointers passed in to the class's members. Then after that they all have a `create()` and a `cleanup()` at minimum and a few getters which return a pointer to the underlying `VkType`...

Comment: @AdrianMole So the model looks like this: member within header: `std::shared_ptr<Image> image_;`  With another class's function that creates the Image. `image_ = std::make_shared<Image>();` then `image_->initialize(physicalDevice, device,...);` after initialization, I would have `image_->create(/*...*/);`.

Comment: @AdrianMole All of my class objects that are Vulkan Types follow that similar pattern.

Comment: Seems a bit like you're trying to fit a square plug into `vkGetSwapChainImagesKHR()`'s round hole.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: "*All of my classes have default empty constructors. They all have an initialize function that must be called first.*" Please stop doing that. You don't have empty destructors on these objects that require a "deinitialize" function to be called before the destructor, so why would you do that for construction? Two-stage object construction should be avoided in C++.

Comment: @NicolBolas Game Engine programming doesn't always follow the typical methodologies and paradigms. My classes are first created via shared_ptr to set aside the required memory which can happen at one point in time, but the underlying Vulkan objects that are contained within them might not be created until a different point in time. The classes are initialized to make sure that the pointers it needs are valid. Then when it is time to create the Vulkan Object I can use my classes' pointers to invoke their `create()` function. I'm also not relying on their destructors to clean up Vulkan objects.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: If you want to set aside the required memory for a class, there's already a way to do that. It's called "allocation"; `allocator<T>::allocate` doesn't create `T`s, after all, despite the return type. When you're ready to use that memory for the object, placement-`new` is always there. And if you're not using destructors to clean up the Vulkan object... why have a wrapper at all? What exactly is the point of `Image`; do you just prefer member functions that much? And if you're not using RAII... why are you using a `shared_ptr` to manage the `Image`'s lifetime?

Comment: @NicolBolas This is due to the fact that one object may require another Vulkan type to be valid as it needs it for construction. I'm not using RAII in the context of Vulkan types for the renderer - engine. When I start to get into building other objects that are not Vulkan specific, then yeah I can use RAII such as if I start to incorporate threads for parallel programming, etc.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: I'm not questioning the needs of a game engine. I'm questioning whether you're implementing those needs in a way that makes sense and actually provides what you think it provides. Your use of `shared_ptr` seems *really* dubious for a low-level resource.

Comment: @NicolBolas I was trying to provide an easy interface to some other user while hiding the implementation details. Since I am using exceptions, I don't want to directly rely on the constructors and destructors... there are methods to create the Vulkan objects.  Now, outside of Vulkan, yeah I might use RAII with other objects such as a Model or Sprite Class, a Scene Class etc.

Comment: @NicolBolas As for right now since I'm making a lot of changes to the code, I'm using shared_ptr to keep memory leaks at a minimum. Down the road once I have all of the Vulkan Objects that I need and the core part of the engine is complete, I may strip them out... and should be able to do it with ease. As for now since I'm doing a lot of debugging and making a lot of changes between classes, they just help to keep the code cleaner for me. I'm in the "design-developmental" stage at the moment... I've changed my design pattern about 3 times since I started this project about 2 weeks ago...

Comment: @NicolBolas So this is not a permanent solution... I'm experimenting to see what kind of things do and do not work with Vulkan to get a better understanding of the API. And to see what produces better results...

Answer (score 4):

Well, I would tell you that you have to create an array (of some kind) of `VkImage`s and pass that to the function. But then your code would "work", but it wouldn't *actually* work. Why?

Because your `Image` type can't store them. See, swapchain images are special; they are not *owned* by your application. That's why you don't create them via the usual `vkCreateImage` call. And it's also why you *cannot* destroy them with the usual `vkDestroyImage` call.

Your `Image` type's destructor no doubt calls `vkDestroyImage` on the image. But you're not allowed to do that for swapchain images because you don't own them.

So at the very least, you would need a special constructor for your `Image` type that both takes an already existing `VkImage` and sets some state in the `Image` so that its destructor won't destroy the image.

So after getting the array of `VkImage` objects from Vulkan, you just iterate through the array and construct your `vector` of your heap-allocated `Image` objects, using the aforementioned specialized constructor for them.

Comment: That makes sense. So in truth within my `SwapChain` class, I can leave it's VkImages as they are. `std::vector<VkImage>` but use the `Image` class for other objects such as the `DepthBuffer`, `Textures`, `Sprite` objects, or some other buffer for pre-post rendering, etc. So I can simply just leave my SwapChain as is, since it will handle them automatically and the SwapChain itself is stored as a `shared_ptr` in another class object.

Comment: If you do not own swap chain images, how would you go about cuda-vulkan interop?  There you want cuda to write directly to swap chain image but that would mean creating the image using a special export flag etc..

Comment: @LegendLength: "*There you want cuda to write directly to swap chain image*" That rather depends on what you're having CUDA actually do. Vulkan is a perfectly serviceable rendering/compute API. If you're using CUDA, that'd generally be for non-rendering tasks. So CUDA compute operations would be writing to buffers or images you *do* own.

Comment: @NicolBolas I want to use cuda for both game physics and ray trace render.  Currently i'm using glsl with good results but i want more control over the assembly in tight loops.  Sadly i'm forced to use cuda otherwise it's a hassle.  But now i can't write directly to swap chain like i used to with pure vulkan.

Comment: @NicolBolas Just to be more direct: Vulkan + GLSL is poorly optimized and shoudn't be used for high performance, given that you get very little control over the generated machine language.  Spir-v isn't good enough it's too general compared to nvidia ptx.

Comment: @LegendLength: "*Vulkan + GLSL is poorly optimized and shoudn't be used for high performance*" And yet, it is being used for "high performance" applications. Well, I don't know about GLSL specifically, but SPIR-V seems perfectly adequate for the task for most developers. And CUDA is not exactly known for being cross-platform ;)